# Shopify iOS Mobile Buy shipping_rate_id "can't be blank"

Tags: ios, shopify, applepay

I've been trying to get Apply Pay working with Shopify's Mobile Buy SDK from the BUYProductViewController, but everytime it returns "Payment Not Completed."

I've narrowed it down to [line 107 in BUYApplePayHelpers.m](https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-ios/blob/master/Mobile%20Buy%20SDK/Mobile%20Buy%20SDK/Utils/BUYApplePayHelpers.m#L107) where at every point before this method, my checkout object has a shippingRateId, and everywhere after it, the shippingRateId is nil.

The error is as follows:

```
errors =     {
        checkout =         {
            "shipping_rate_id" =             (
                                {
                    code = blank;
                    message = "can't be blank";
                    options =                     {
                    };
                }
            );
```

Any ideas what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with latest SDK update: https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-ios/commit/837165d1e48516bc9377e0f1fa3d5245546a4c0c

Answer (score 0):

I've been threw the same problem. I was setting checkout shipping rates to nil:

```
rtrncheckout.shippingRate = nil
```

because my store doesn't apply shipping rates. My solution was to just remove this line.
I work in Swift but i think you can easily translate this if you work with ObjC :)

Comment: Is this using the BUYProductViewController or is it a custom store setup?